# Disabling HTML button with jQuery using TypeSript

Tags: jquery, typescript

I have a web page that has some buttons, I want to enable/disable the buttons based on the click. I used jQuery and it worked fine using

```js
btn.attr("disabled", true /* or false */)
```

but now I want to change the code and use TypeScript and I get following error.

> TS2345 (TS) Argument of type 'boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | number | ((this: HTMLElement, index: number, attr: string) => string | number | void)'.

Is there any other way using `btn.attr()` to enable/disable the buttons? I tried searching on Stack Overflow but I only found many questions on jQuery itself not using TypeScript.

Interestingly when I try to run the same code in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tmow867b/) it does work...

Comment: You should be using `btn.prop("disabled", true | false)`. See e.g., [.prop() vs .attr()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5874652/215552).

Comment: @HereticMonkey Thanks. Is there anything I'm missing as why it works in JSFiddle?

Comment: Read the answers to the duplicate. They explain it. JSFiddle is not the tool to use to test TypeScript. Use [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5wFYEUCeBTKHOAMyghDgHIMBHAVwJ0oG4AoVgGz3gCMYA7AIxwAvHAAkACgBEAYj5DpASgB0AYw7A1Aa0l5+yHlwBCAgExK2XXudESZ888vWadeg0bymhl9sTr8ajDAEPxw+oYm5pJKcADerHBwCoIqyDAwUDIAJsCokXjZ0gA0cJkMvkkKZmkZWdK5+Z5FpcTIHKh4vgC+fgFBIWERnt6CMfGJyea1mTl5BS1lUBVsVQKp6bMN880lJO2dPaxAA)